# MS Word Fields: Writing fractions in English

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I am familiar with using fields to write out integers and decimals in English.

Is there a way to make "1/2" read as 'one-half' or some equivalent?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you need. You want a text replacement that will literally type "one half" if you write "1/2" or do you want it to substitute the fraction glyph ½? Also, what platform are you on? This kind of replacement is trivial on Mac, but not so easy on Win.

Comment: I want the former e.g. 2/3 -> two thirds

Comment: @worduser - Your question is not clear you should consider performing an [edit] on it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, although it will require disabling Word's automatic
handling of fractions, in order to replace "1/2" by "one-half".

You will need to go into menu *File > Options > Proofing >
AutoFormat As You Type* and disable the option of
"Fractions (1/2) with fraction character (½)".
This will disable this option for all fractions.

Then you need to go into menu *File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect*
and enter your replacement:

[image]

Click through OK to the end, and this is done.

Comment: Note that with this solution you can't use the cells value for calculation anymore.

Comment: You also have to add every relevant fraction so it's hardly a scale of solution.

Comment: This doesn't use fields, and also like Ramhound said

Comment: Fields isn't the best solution. I would really suggest using another mnemonic than "1/2". For example, use "oh" so "o-h-blank" will be replaced by "one-half". That way you don't need to disable fractions.

Comment: I'm creating auto forms that other users will populate with questionnaires, hence the fields. I was hoping I could kill 2 birds by having users input the math notation. Word handles most other numberic -> english transformations pretty well